# Custom font not working on mobile devices

Tags: css, font-face

I have used CSS rule `@font-face` for my font Rajdhani. Works perfect on desktop but not on Android and IOS devices:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Rajdhani";
    src: url("/fonts/rajdhani-light.ttf") format("truetype"),
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Rajdhani";
    src: url("/fonts/rajdhani-medium.ttf") format("truetype"),
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Rajdhani";
    src: url("/fonts/rajdhani-regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Rajdhani";
    src: url("/fonts/rajdhani-semibold.ttf") format("truetype"),
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Rajdhani";
    src: url("/fonts/rajdhani-bold.ttf") format("truetype"),
}
```

Comment: Have you tried without `src:`? I'm not sure it's necessary for `.ttf` (truetype) fonts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you should add the files in other formats as well, for example, go to [online web font generator](https://transfonter.org/) and convert your font then add all types because this has to do with the operating system

```
@font-face {
font-family: "CustomFont";
src: url("CustomFont.eot");
src: url("CustomFont.woff") format("woff"),
url("CustomFont.otf") format("opentype"),
url("CustomFont.svg#filename") format("svg");
}
```